# Why are 副助詞 called "adverbial" particles?

Tags: particles, adverbs, adverbial

For some context, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles), the following serve as examples of 副助詞:

> Adverbial particles (副助詞, fuku-joshi)
> ばかり, まで, だけ, ほど, くらい, など, なり, やら

**Question:** Why are adverbial particles (副助詞) called "adverbial" (副詞) particles?

Is it that all of these sorts of particles can combine with nouns (or noun phrases) to form adverbs (副詞)? Is *that* the defining feature of what it means to be an 副助詞?

E.g.

> **りんごばかり**食べています。

Here りんごばかり ("only apples") is acting as an adverbial phrase which modifies 食べています?

---

**EDIT:** I am also trying to understand the dictionary definition of 副助詞 from [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%89%AF%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E/):

> ふく‐じょし【副助詞】 の解説
>
> 助詞の一。種々の語に付き、それらの語にある意味を添えて、副詞のように下の**用言や活用連語**を修飾・限定する類の助詞。現代語では「さえ」「まで」「ばかり」「だけ」「ほど」「くらい（ぐらい）」「など」「やら」など、古語では「だに」「すら」「さへ」「のみ」「ばかり」「など」「まで」など。

However this part is confusing me:

> 副詞のように下の**用言や活用連語**を修飾

If I'm reading this correctly, 副助詞 can only come after 用言や活用連語 (conjugatable words) to form something that is adverbial? But can't 副助詞 come after pure nouns (as in 「りんごばかり」, where りんご is a non-conjugatable word) to form adverbial phrases too? If that's the case, why is the definition emphasizing 用言や活用連語 here?

Answer (score 2):

In basic terms, a 副助詞【ふくじょし】 (adverbial particle) is a 助詞【じょし】 (particle) that acts like a 副詞【ふくし】 (adverb).

> > 副詞のように下の**用言や活用連語**を修飾
>
> If I'm reading this correctly, 副助詞 can only come after 用言や活用連語 (conjugatable words) to form something that is adverbial?

You're not reading this correctly.

The 「下の」 refers to the *following* 用言【ようげん】や活用連語【かつようれんご】 (inflecting word or conjugating phrase), which these particles 修飾【しゅうしょく】 (modify or qualify).

The earlier bit says what these 副助詞【ふくじょし】 attach to:

> 種々【しゅじゅ】の語【ご】に付【つ】き、
> *attaches to various words,*

> But can't 副助詞 come after pure nouns (as in 「りんごばかり」, where りんご is a non-conjugatable word) to form adverbial phrases too?

Yes, these can come after nouns, as in your example.

> If that's the case, why is the definition emphasizing 用言や活用連語 here?

I hope the explanation further above suffices.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) Just to clarify more though: you're saying that the adverbial particles (like ばかり) are themselves *adverbs*? Or are they only considered adverbial (not the particle itself, but the particle + the noun) when they combine with nouns and noun phrases?

Comment: I also find the name confusing but for a different reason. Don’t most particle (or postpositional) phrases modify 用言 and 活用連語? And some of those classified as “adverbial” can form noun phrases, a feature that is not always applicable to 格助詞. What’s particularly “adverbial” about them?

Comment: Some particles specify arguments to the verb, like を or も or が -- these tell us things about the nouns doing the action, or having the action done to them.  The adverbial particles are a little different from adverbs alone, in that the particle versions must attach to a noun or noun phrase, whereas a plain adverb doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: Particles like に and で form phrases that modify a verb. Corresponding prepositional phrases in English, such as “to …”, “at …”, “by …”, etc. would be adverbial phrases, as opposed to adjectival. (Phrases ending with の are adjectival.) Phrases ending with ばかり, だけ, etc., on the other hand, can also be nominal, as well as adverbial. This is why I think the name is confusing.

Comment: @aguijonazo, I'm confused by your comparison to English prepositional phrases, where you say _"as opposed to adjectival"_ -- given the structure of your paragraph, that seems to imply that perhaps you view the phrases with に and で as adjectival? As you note, these _"form phrases that modify a verb"_, which would be adverbial. :)  Separately, could you provide examples of だけ or ばかり in nominal usage in a way that does not include any adverbial sense at all? I can't think of any at the moment, but then again it's early here and the coffee hasn't kicked in yet. :)

Comment: I really don’t know how I managed to confuse you so much. English prepositional phrases can be either adverbial or adjectival, but the usages corresponding to に and で are adverbial. That means に and で are also adverbial, as opposed to の, which is adjectival. My doubt is why だけ and ばかり should be called “adverbial” when に and で are also adverbial, and besides, だけ and ばかり can be nominal, which に and で cannot be. When だけ or ばかり is followed by another particle, as in 〜だけがある, the phrase that ends with だけ or ばかり has no adverbial function. It’s just a noun phrase like any other.

Comment: @aguijonazo, in those phrases (that I can think of) that have constructions like 〔だけ・ばかり〕がある, the adverbial particle can be removed and you still have a grammatical sentence.  It's not the 副助詞 that's acting as a nominal, but rather the nominal that comes just before it.

Comment: But it remains a fact that だけ and ばかり can form part of a noun phrase like that while に and で can't, and I'm left with the same doubt. Which are more "adverbial"?

Comment: @aguijonazo, what of examples like 「一緒にがいいですね」 or 「終わった後でがいいんじゃないか」? Are those not nominals ending in に and で respectively? I wonder if the issue here is syntax rather than something inherent in the pieces we're looking at?

Comment: I see those as short and informal versions of more properly constructed sentences such as 一緒に行くのが〜 and 終わった後でするのが〜. That's not the case with だけ and ばかり. Among case particles, から can be used that way, but not に and で.